# Run a Ruby script that populates MongoDB in a Rails Application.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

I am new to RoR. I have a Ruby Script that populates MongoDB database. I want to run this script in my Rails application and display on front end. How to proceed?

Comment: Do you want to poplulate it only one time?

Answer (score 0):

Place the Ruby script in the Controller of the Rails application. Pass the query results to the Front end page through .html_safe command.
e.g

In the Controller:
@query_result=tuple_result

[tuple_result is the result back from MongoDB]

At the Front end:
**<%= @tuple %>**